# Notepad++ Syntax Highlight: How can I set a delimiter with spaces?

Tags: windows-8, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I'm creating my User Define Language in notepad++, and I have a delimiter set like this:

**open:** try 
**escape:** 
**close:** :

But when I type `entry`, the *`try`* gets highlighted, as the delimiter I've set. How can I block that from happening? Any help is welcome.

I'm using windows 8, *with notepad++ Je Suis Charlie*.

Comment: Delimiting doesn't seem as good a match for this case as code folding. Can you give some examples of what the `try`-`:` pair should look like in context?

Comment: It's for this use: `try` *`code`* `:`, and I want code to be highlighted, since I don't want the default color in there.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I'm not sure N++ can do this easily; if you go and define a full language the way C#, say, is defined you could probably manage it but I don't know how much more work that would be.

Comment: I saw that creating a UDL in N++ creates a file. So maybe by editing that file directly, with a little bit of research, I would be able to do that so?

Comment: You could certainly try that, but the file, and I think even the XML schema, that it uses for UDLs is not the same as for normal languages, and I'm not sure even the format has enough flexibility.

Comment: That's right, but I saw that you're able to do that with keywords, so why not with delimiters?

Comment: When I was having a little look about defining a delimiter with a space in n++, I saw in the [notepad++ site](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org) a page about the release of version 6.2, where they said that you were able to do that in there. From what I know, Je Suis Charlie was released after v6.2. [Here's the link](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.2-release-udl2.html).

Comment: Notepad++ is now on version 6.7.7

Comment: I know, but than what's written in there should be true... Doesn't look like...

Answer (score 0):

After checking [UDL 2.0 online documentation](http://udl20.weebly.com/index.html), I do not think it is currently possible. You either use what is offered or write your own highlighter in C++ or switch to editor with more advanced UDL capabilities (e.g. [SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/)) which allows much more control over the highlighter – but, of course, that parser is adequately more difficult to define.